# cmake error after changing gcc on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake

I have replaced my default gcc with gcc45:

```
sudo port install gcc45
sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc45
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.3
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

But now if I attempt to configure a project with [`cmake`](http://cmake.org/) I get error:

```
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/local/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "/opt/local/bin/gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
...
/opt/local/bin/gcc -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -o
 CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c [...]/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
```

I searched `cmake` documentation for an option not to assume a Darwin environment, but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Only the Apple-supplied compilers support the `--arch` option.  It's an Apple modification.  In general, it's not a good idea to use a non-Apple-supplied C compiler unless you *really* need something in a newer one.  There are other Apple-supplied modifications to the tool chain as well.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the system name as anything but Darwin fixed the problem:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Linux" ..
```

[CMake Cross Compiling](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling)